# How to Reduc the while loop with code sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Master two hundred strokes a day , each corresponding to one hundred strokes than master sub- files, a total of one year is 7.3 million pen information
Here is my SQL command

```
DECLARE @day INT =0
DECLARE @everyday DATETIME
DECLARE @mastercount INT=0
DECLARE @detailcount INT=0
DECLARE @state NVARCHAR(3)='ship'
DECLARE @user VARCHAR(8)='Sid'
DECLARE @masterid INT

SET nocount ON

WHILE( @day <= 364 )
  BEGIN
      IF( @day = 122 )
        BEGIN
            SET @user='danny'
            SET @state='stock'
        END
      ELSE IF( @day = 244 )
        BEGIN
            SET @user='annie'
            SET @state='ship'
        END

      SET @everyday=Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), @day)

      WHILE( @mastercount < 200 )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO OrderMaster
                        (OrderCustomerName,orderdate,orderstate)
            VALUES      (@user,@everyday,@state)

            SELECT @masterid = C_Id
            FROM   OrderMaster
            WHERE  C_Id = Scope_identity()

            WHILE( @detailcount < 100 )
              BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO OrderDetail
                              (C_OrderMasterId,C_ProductMasterId,Quantity)
                  VALUES      (@masterid,1 + ( 21 - 1 ) * Rand(),Rand() * 100 + 1)

                  SET @detailcount=@detailcount + 1
              END

            SET @detailcount=0--
            SET @mastercount=@mastercount + 1
        END

      SET @mastercount=0
      SET @day=@day + 1
  END

SET nocount OFF
```

However
The total time taken 51min
Too long ~~
How can I shorten the time?
Thank you ~!

Comment: You can use a number table to replace `WHILE` loops with efficient set based operations. See first answer to this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I'm using google to find relevant information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Use `Recursive CTE` to generate records which will avoid **`row by row`** insert in your `while loop`.

```
DECLARE @day INT =0
DECLARE @everyday DATETIME
DECLARE @mastercount INT=0
DECLARE @detailcount INT=0
DECLARE @state NVARCHAR(3)='ship'
DECLARE @user VARCHAR(8)='Sid'
DECLARE @masterid INT

SET nocount ON

WHILE( @day <= 364 )
  BEGIN
      IF( @day = 122 )
        BEGIN
            SET @user='danny'
            SET @state='stock'
        END
      ELSE IF( @day = 244 )
        BEGIN
            SET @user='annie'
            SET @state='ship'
        END

      SET @everyday=Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), @day);

      WITH cte
           AS (SELECT 1 id,@user [user],@everyday everyday,@state [state]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT id + 1,[user],everyday,[state]
               FROM   cte
               WHERE  id < 200)
      INSERT INTO OrderMaster
                  (OrderCustomerName,orderdate,orderstate)
      SELECT [user],everyday,[state]
      FROM   cte
      OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

      SELECT @masterid = C_Id
      FROM   OrderMaster
      WHERE  C_Id = Scope_identity();

      WITH cte
           AS (SELECT 1 id, @masterid masterid,
                      ( ( 21 - 1 ) * Checksum(LEFT(Newid(), 1)) ) / 100 C_ProductMasterId,
                      ( Checksum(LEFT(Newid(), 1)) * 100 + 1 ) / 100    Quantity
               UNION ALL
               SELECT id + 1, masterid,
                      ( ( 21 - 1 ) * Checksum(LEFT(Newid(), 1)) ) / 100 C_ProductMasterId,
                      ( Checksum(LEFT(Newid(), 1)) * 100 + 1 ) / 100    Quantity
               FROM   cte
               WHERE  id < 100 * 200)
      INSERT INTO OrderDetail
                  (C_OrderMasterId,C_ProductMasterId,Quantity)
      SELECT masterid,
             C_ProductMasterId,
             Quantity
      FROM   cte
      OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

      SET @day=@day + 1
  END 


    SET nocount OFF
```

Comment: Seem great, but it seems more than my current degree , and I will work hard to understand , Thanks

Comment: It seems there should be my question wrong , it should be 
365day * 200master * 100detail
now MasterTable Data is correct
DetailTable Date is Incorrect
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxbWqkwkGqNaVDh1NTBRRHl2c3M/view

Comment: @SID We don't have date in details table

Comment: sorry my bad is DetailTable Data is Incorrect not Date XDD
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxbWqkwkGqNaVDh1NTBRRHl2c3M/view
this Picture is Detailtable result OrderMasterId start with 200 total 20K rows 
but 
OrderMasterId should be start with 1 total 100 rows
101 row OrderMasterId should be start with 2 total 100 rows

This result is the 365day * 200master * 100detail
thank you